# Scanner android application

Tags: android

We are developing an android application for document scanner.

This application is having feature to edit the image like adding magic color, grey mode, Black white,etc. this application has the option to scan "N" number of pages and convert it into PDF at the end.

The flow of the application is First activity is taking photo of the image and the second activity for cropping the image and third activity for editing the image like applying magic color, grey mode and black/white conversion. And in the third activity we have add button,clicking on it will go back to first activty and the same process continues.Once all the images scanned, third activity is haivng done button, clicking on it will create pdf and close the application.

Now the problem is after scanning some 35 pages, it throws out of memory error because we are always keeping original and modified bitmaps as List in the code because its possible for the user to go back to previous images and edit it.  At that time i need original version of the image also.

Could you please help me out on the below items.

1) where to keep the bitmaps in this scenario?
2) Is there any way to store the image in the external card and reading it everytime on need basis?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Store the bitmap as cache.

```
out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

It is prefetable to use cache directory to store such a file rather than storing it persistently. `getCacheDir(`) will return the path to the directory.